# Color calibration tool for Linux

Tags: linux, color, gnome, arch-linux

I need to calibrate my laptop screen. But doing this with some picture from the internet in my browser (which I don't trust in terms of colors) and having to fiddle with `xrandr` settings in the shell is not the ideal environment. I'm searching for a software that helps me calibrating my screen (Gamma, brightness, color, ...) using some images and sliders or some other way of real-time feedback. Somewhat like the Windows color calibration.

I do not want to have to buy some hardware to do this, like for the Gnome built-in calibration.

My system: Arch Linux, Gnome, XOrg

Comment: When you say "images and sliders", are they paper things, or software things?

Comment: Paper things? With "slider", I meant some interactive way to change display settings like Gamma with a live preview. With "images" I mean reference images I can use to tweak the slider until the screen is adjusted. You find tons of gamma correction images on the internet.

Comment: I was lucky finding a profile for my (external) monitor [here](http://www.tftcentral.co.uk/articles/icc_profiles.htm). Imo this is way better than using monitor calibration from the menu, although it won't be as perfect as specialized hardware.